# hover effect opacity ie8

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.boxgrid.slidedown').hover(function(){
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'0'},{queue:false,duration:300});
}, function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'1'},{queue:false,duration:300});
    });

    //Full Caption Sliding (Hidden to Visible)
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(function(){
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'1'},{queue:false,duration:250});
    }, function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({opacity:'0'},{queue:false,duration:250});
    });
});
```

I add hover effect on image.
In IE8, .cover div already appear first.
Why it is?

Comment: You should post your HTML code. Perhaps even elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: here's html code.

               <div class="boxgrid captionfull">
                    <img src="{$image_tiny}" class=thumb />
                        <div class="cover boxcaption">
                            <h1>{$product_name}</h1>
                            <h3><s>w</s> {$product_price}</h3>
                        </div>
               </div>

Comment: My guess is that you have to hide the hover effect with CSS so your jQuery code can show it. But I can't really make out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First in css add `.cover {display:none}`, Have you tried using fadeIn/fadeOut

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Full Caption Sliding (Hidden to Visible)
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull').hover(function(){
    $(".cover", this).fadeIn(250);
    }, function() {
    $(".cover", this).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

You can tweak it little nore if you want add .stop()